# How do I host WordPress classified website images on an external source?

Tags: wordpress, image, fetch, cdn

I have a classified website [pkwhistle.com](https://pkwhistle.com/) that is leading multiple countries and has a huge collection of images media. Is there any way to store newly uploaded listing images automatically store outside WordPress and fetch back to my site. [clasificadospr.com](https://clasificadospr.com/) is the best example of my idea. Because this website is using service which I am actually asking about. It's using the "thumbor" service. Please help me in this matter so I can increase the speed of my website. More than 10thousand images on a website can kill speed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's called hosting/loading your images from a CDN, and there are many providers that work nicely with Wordpress!

With 10.000 images you mostly end up with a premium solution such as [WP offload Media from Deliciousbrains](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/) (highly recommended and I am not in any way affiliated to them, just love their products). [They also have a free version](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/).

You can hook it up with all the big assets storage providers (digitalOcean Spaces, Amazon's AWS)

And integration with WP is great, it syncs between the CDN and your Wordpress Library.

Alternatively, there are some free options, you can use [photon from Wordpress](https://jetpack.com/support/site-accelerator/), it does almost the same, but hosted on photon's servers. It comes with the Jetpack plugin.

Another free option is [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/wordpress_integration) (they have a plugin as well). But it has a limited free plan.

Good luck!